# Position of main navigation bar runs outside of auto area

Tags: css, wordpress, navigation

I'm a self-taught website developer (still learning a lot) and I'm running into some difficulty with the styling of my main menu/navigation bar. The problem is that my menu is running out the specified/fixed/auto position. I'm using Wordpress.org, it's Untitled theme. It's doing this: http://www.betweenparentheses.net

This is my code:

```
.main-navigation {
float: right;
font-family: 'arvo', georgia;
font-size: 24px;
padding-top: 0px !important;
text-transform: uppercase;
clear:right;
margin-top: 0px;
}

.main-navigation ul {
list-style: none;
margin: -44px;
padding-left: -5px;
float: right;
}
.main-navigation li {
display: inline-block;
position: right;
margin-left: 4px;
padding-left: 16px !important;
}
```

Comment: Where __should__ those links be displayed?

Comment: They should appear on the right, but as you can see, the menu option "writing, the portion of "ing" of writing is out of the black box area.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You specified the margin for the `.main-navigation ul` incorrectly. You gave only one value to the margin, which means, that all four sides will have this negative margin. This is why your menu is running outside the viewport.

You should specify it like this:

```
.main-navigation ul {
list-style: none;
margin: -44px 0 0 0;
padding-left: -5px;
float: right;
}
```

I'll explain this a little bit:

The four segments in the margin property represent the element's sides clockwise: top right bottom left.

You only needed to adjust the top margin to change the element's position on the screen.

I would also recommend to add a small positive right margin (22px, for example), to give the menu some spacing in the right side as well:

```
margin: -44px 22px 0 0;
```

**Update:**

In order to get your menu to the desired position, replace the CSS for `.main-navigation` with this:

```
.main-navigation {
  float: none; /*Changed this*/
  font-family: 'arvo', georgia;
  font-size: 24px;
  padding-top: 0px !important;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  clear: right;
  margin-top: 0px;
  max-width: 1000px; /*Added this*/
  margin: 0 auto; /*and this*/
}
```

Also remove the left and right margin from your `.main-navigation ul` rule:

Replace this

```
margin: -44px 18px 0 0;
```

with this

```
margin: -44px 0 0 0;
```

Comment: Apologies, we're having severe wind and my internet connection isn't very good. Your answer did solve my problem -- thanks a lot. However, I do want both, my social media bar and my navigation bar to match on the right side. Right now they're asymmetrical. I've toyed around with the values as you explained but nothing seems to really change. Should I be looking at something else? Thanks!

Comment: Actually, I got it! I kept playing around with the values as you explained them and I got what I wanted! THANKS SO MUCH!

Comment: I recommend to use my updated solution as it works on all screen resolutions.